# How do I change this into a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a small script that will get enormous if I do not find a way to put it in a for loop.

```
if(buildLevel >= 2){
    $( "#house1").html( "<img style='width: 200px; height: 150px; top:0; left: 0; position: absolute;' data-u='image' src='images/house1.jpg' />"  );
}
if(buildLevel >= 3){
    $( "#house2").html( "<img style='width: 200px; height: 150px; top:0; left: 0; position: absolute;' data-u='image' src='images/house2.jpg' />"  );
}
if(buildLevel >= 4){
    $( "#house3").html( "<img style='width: 200px; height: 150px; top:0; left: 0; position: absolute;' data-u='image' src='images/house3.jpg' />"  );
}
```

So as you can see. All the numbers including the image name should increase by 1 every time. So if there would come an extra 'house', it would be like this:

```
if(buildLevel >= 5){
    $( "#house4").html( "<img style='width: 200px; height: 150px; top:0; left: 0; position: absolute;' data-u='image' src='images/house4.jpg' />"  );
}
```

I hope anyone can help me. I couldn't find a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this, using *buildLevel* as end condition of a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i < buildLevel; i++) {
    $( "#house" + i).html( "<img style='width: 200px; height: 150px; top:0; left: 0; position: absolute;' data-u='image' src='images/house'+i+'.jpg' />"  );
}
```

Comment: Using this as the cleanest solution. Thanks

Comment: See man may be you are in hurry this not the correct answer any way. house should be one less then of counter, its clearly mentioned in question.

Comment: Fixed that part for myself. The rest was very decent honestly.

Comment: Thanks for applying the fix to this answer, @deepeshkumar.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( var i=1 ; i< 6; i++){
 if(buildLevel >= i){
      $( "#house"+i).html( "<img style='width: 200px; height: 150px; top:0; left:          0; position: absolute;' data-u='image' src='images/house'+i+'.jpg' />"  );
  }
}
```

Comment: See man house should be one less then of counter, its clearly mentioned in question. See my answer.